# Mistake in Conway's Analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reviewing [Conway's complex analysis book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387903283) on page 5 and I think he made a mistake:

[image]

Following my calculations the cube of the second solution is $-2\sqrt 2$ instead of $1$.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah the second and third roots in that list should be $\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm i\sqrt{3})$

Comment: Note the norm of the root given in Conway is $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a mistake in the book, the cube roots of unity are

$$1, \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2},$$

and your result of $-2\sqrt{2}$ for the cube of the second (and third) is also correct.